# Cannot remove background fill/highlight from labels generated through Easycustomlabeling

Tags: qgis, labeling

In QGIS, I cannot remove the background fill or highlight that appears as a rectangle behind the text from the easycustomlabeling labels. The background fill is white with black text, and I want the black text only. I have tried clicking and unclicking the "highlight pinned labels" button at the top but it does not change anything.

Comment: I had this same problem, but it was only for the QGIS display. When I made a map in Composer the labels were OK. Just an FYI for anyone else fighting this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to uncheck the Background > Draw Background option:

[image]

Any other setting you want to disable, look for the setting to be controlled by an expression, and disable it:[image]

Comment: Thank you- I'm not sure why I was so confused about this. I think I was in the wrong tab in the properties box.